# How to access variable declared inside promise in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am new to the AngularJS, I need to access the variable which is assigned inside the promise in Javascript

```
this.reqData= this.profileService.getData();
var resp1 = angular.fromJson(this.reqData);
this.data1;

var that = this;
resp1.$promise.then(function (data) {
  that.data1= data.resource.resource;
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

console.log(this.data1);
```

the variable data1 can be accessed from HTML but it is showing `undefined` in Javascript

Comment: You don't access it outside of the promise. You cannot fetch the value from the future (unless you invent time travel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous. The problem is that, when you get to the `console.log`, **the `$promise.then` code didn't run yet**.
You have to wait for the promise to be **fulfilled** before you can access that data.

Any operation you want to apply to the value must be done **inside** that callback function you're passing to `then`:

```
resp1.$promise.then(function (data) {
  var data1 = data.resource.resource;
  // do all your processing on data1 *here*
  console.log(data1);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

---

AngularJS is able to update your HTML when it gets the data, because `$promise` is Angular-aware – it knows that, once your callback has run, it has to tell AngularJS to refresh/repaint your page (and thus update the data).

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't know when the `promise` returns, so it won't be immediately available for you in `console.log(this.data1);`

You can access your data inside the `callback`.

```
resp1.$promise.then(function (data) {
  that.data1= data.resource.resource;
  }).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```